# Copying Aggregate: Why shouldn't we also copy objects existing outside the Aggregate boundary?

Tags: domain-driven-design

When application wants to create new Aggregate based on an already existing Aggregate, we are allowed to copy everything ( except for the inner entities's IDs ) inside the existing Aggregate into a new Aggregate. But if some inner object references an object outside the Aggregate boundary, we're not allowed to also copy the referenced object.

a) I know Aggregates should mind their own business and not interfere with other Aggregate's life cycle, but what exactly would be wrong if we also copied the object existing outside the Aggregate boundary?

Comment: Would you provide a more specific example?

Comment: @eulerfx: Isn't this a general rule, regardless of what kind of domain model we have ( at least that's how I understood the author of DDD: Tackling Complexity... - he never explicitly said it, but I thought he implied it )?

Comment: The reason I ask for example is to glean something from your domain that may affect the answer. Copying of aggregates is not something that is explicitly covered in DDD so there may be caveats in your case.

Comment: @eulerfx: Sorry, I don't have any particular example. I'm currently just trying to get through the whole book hoping that I won't bump into some "too complicated for my IQ" concept, since then it would be all over

Comment: @eulerfx: Just to be sure, so author isn't really implying anywhere in the book ( and in particular on page 174 with "affected nothing outside the Aggregate boundary" ) that this is some general rule?

Comment: You can certainly copy references to outside objects, because those are just references and don't affect the transactional integrity of aggregate. What is interesting however is the reason for the copy.

Comment: @eulerfx: I know answer to the following question may not be possible since it may depend on specific examples, but still ... why would copying the outside object itself affect the transactional integrity of the aggregate?

Comment: It may affect the integrity of the copied object, depending on what that object is. This is why the nature of the copying is important - it depends on what is copied and why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have an aggregate `Order` with a collection of `OrderLine` objects and you want to create a new order based on an existing one you would only copy the order and its associated order lines.  Even though the order line may have a reference to a `Product` you wouldn't copy the product since it is not part of the aggregate.

The order line should ideally not even have a reference to a product instance but rather just hold the product id.

As eulerfx has mentioned the reason behind the copying may give one more insight :)

Comment: "The order line should ideally not even have a reference to a product instance but rather just hold the product id." I understand that Aggregates should make certain no consistency rules are violated within its own aggregate, but how do you figure referencing a Product could somehow violate any of aggregate's consistency rules?

Comment: It isn't so much that referencing a Product will break the consistency rules but rather about creating a very distinct AR with a well defined edge.  In fact, having a product/service of some kind on an order line *is* required for consistency.

Comment: "In fact, having a product/service of some kind on an order line is required for consistency." Could you elaborate on why having a Product    on order line is required for consistency?

Comment: ...an order line is typically defined as a product with a quantity with possibly additinal data. Therefore, for an order line to be consistent it must reference a product - otherwise there is not point to it.